# Error runaway argument, missing }

Tags: graphics, floats, compilation-error

I suddenly have several runaway arguments in several figures, while I don't think that I am missing something.

These are the lines of my script:

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Figures/00-figures/metylblauw.jpg}
    \caption{Results of methylene blue tests on filter paper.}
    \label{fig:filterpaper}
\end{figure}
```

And this is the error message:

> ```
> Runaway argument?
>
> {Specific gravity results{\label {tab:specificgrav} Results of the sp\ETC.
> ! Paragraph ended before \caption@prepareanchor was complete.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \par 
> l.617     \centering
> ```

Comment: As a first attempt try what happens if you compile a document that only consists of the offending figure. Not only will that perhaps tell you something about the error, it will also allow you to post a full (non-)working example here, which always helps with trying to find out what's wrong.

Comment: The error refers to a different part of your document.

Comment: If your editor has brace checking, add an extra } and see where the matching { shows up.

Comment: It seems you have a caption for a table  in your document with the label `\label {tab:specificgrav} ` defined in it. Search for it -- perhaps line 617 in your tex file? -- and look for the missing `}` ...

Comment: The code you post is clearly not related to the error message that you show. the error is about a line `Specific gravity r....` which has a missing `}` somewhere close by.